# Android - list of numbers with incrementer decrementer

Tags: android

I want to have a list of numeric EditText fields with incrementers and decrementers (functionally like spin-buttons). The numbers are supposed to be percentages adding up to 100. Finalizing the values should only be possible when this happens. I also want the incrementers to grey out when the total reaches 100 and the decrementers to grey out when the total reaches 0. I'm also including another text view that shows the difference between the current total and 100. What is a good way to do this? Should I just have 2*n different buttons with the listeners doing all this work? Or is there a neater way?

**Update:** 
The principal way of changing the values will be the up/down buttons. The text being editable is just for a secondary matter of convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the incrementing Buttons transparent, over the EditTexts and make them translucent if the value reaches its minimum/maximum.
An alternative is to have a general incrementing and decrementing Button and a spinner or radio Buttons for selection.
But the consideration cannot be finalised without knowing the use of your values and the handling you have in mind.

EDIT: The SeekBar would be perfect for values of not more than 100 without additional Buttons.

Comment: The radio button/spinner idea does not seem suitable. The user is not expected to set the values one by one, but modify them in arbitrary order.

Comment: For this purpose there is the direct edit of the field with the Keyboard. Set limits and there you go. Another option would be a slider, that would also make a nice visual effect.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood what I said. The increments will not be done to the same value repeatedly, so would result in lots of accesses to the spinner/radio which would be cumbersome from a user perspective.

Comment: Just check out the Seekbar, as I think this has potential for many values.